# How do you clear a windows media player playlist programmatically c#

Tags: c#, windows, media-player, media

My program uses windows media player in C# so that I can play almost any sound file. Some sounds need to play in succession, one after the other. The only way I could think to do that was with playlists, but I can't figure out how to clear the playlist between calls to the windows media player.

**How can I play sounds, one after the other, in windows media player, without running into problems from previous playlists?**

Thanks

My code:

```
WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist playlist = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("myplaylist");

WMPLib.IWMPMedia media;

foreach (string question in questionURL)
   {
       media = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(question);
       playlist.appendItem(media);
       media = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(answer);
       playlist.appendItem(media);

       axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = playlist;
       axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
       axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.remove(playlist);\\one of my many failed attempts at clearing the playlist. It doesn't throw an error, it doesn't clear the playlist either.
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [PlaylistCollection.remove()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564116%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So I think you could remove the playlist with:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.remove("myplaylist");
```

Then simply create it again:

```
playlist = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("myplaylist");
```

Comment: When I try the string "myplaylist" the way you show I get the error "cannot convert from 'string' to 'WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist'"

Comment: Remove the quotes and pass in the **class level reference** to the playlist...so: `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.remove(playlist);`

Comment: When I do that it still leaves the playlist file. Is there some option to remove the playlist all together?

Comment: Not sure...try using the [setDeleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564117(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact solution if you want to clear your playlist.

```
playlist.clear();
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = playlist;
```